# collapses the tree on the click of parent node - d3.js and Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to use this [Example](https://bl.ocks.org/bumbeishvili/dbc0beff4baf64674b0f05b94cb4462e) for creating the organization chart. >> d3.js v3 (old version)

currently, it seems all are in a working state

the click on the circle "+" button child nodes collapses, all good

but I want to make it happen like when the user tries to click on any place within the entire parent node, then also the child node group get collapses

EDIT:
So either with "+" button or on click at any place on a parent node

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two children for each node in your chart; the first one is contents (img, title and etc) and the second one is the collapse button.
To accomplish your task, you can modify the `<rect>` tag inside the second `<g data-id="x">` tag.
Here's the code you need to replace with your own.

```
<rect class="node-collapse-right-rect" height="80" fill="transparent" x="0" y="0" width="210" style="
"></rect>
```

Comment: Hello, do you mean just have to change the fill attribute? ```<rect class="node-collapse-right-rect" height="7" fill="black" x="203" y="73" width="7"></rect>```

if not then please share details with differences, it would be fewer complications to understand :)

Comment: You should also change the x and y coordinates to zero, as well as the width and height of your element (in your case width="210" and height="80"). By doing this, you will spread clickable sections around your node.

Comment: Hello, can we make a chart vertically? when expand child node it can display vertically